# How to customize rows of xlsx table before export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xlsx

I get an array of objects(dicts) as input like the following example.

```
 const data = [
    { id: 1, serviceId: 1, title: "A", model: "A", },
    { id: 1, serviceId: 1, title: "T", model: "b", },
    { id: 1, serviceId: 2, title: "R", model: "A", },
    { id: 2, serviceId: 55, title: "Q", model: "A", },
    { id: 3, serviceId: 58, title: "S", model: "p", },
    { id: 3, serviceId: 58, title: "S", model: "m", },
    { id: 3, serviceId: 66, title: "y", model: "A", }
    ];
```

I want to cutomize the rows when I export the payload of `data` to an xlsx file. For the export, I am using the following function.

```
export const ExportToExcel = ({ apiData, fileName }) => {
    const fileType =
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8";
    const fileExtension = ".xlsx";

    const exportToCSV = (apiData, fileName) => {
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(apiData);
        const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
        const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
        const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
    };

    return (
        <Button
            onClick={(e) => exportToCSV(apiData, fileName)}
            sx={{ m: 2 }}
            variant="contained"
        >
            Export as xlsx
        </Button>
    );
};
```

For the customization, I want to get as an output something similar to what is showed in the following table:
[xlsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIpBX.png)

I tried to achieve that by looping over each dictionary and regrouping elements that have the same parameters but the code was just massive.

Is there any simpler way to achieve this?

I am calling the export function in the main component as follows:

```
<ExportToExcel apiData={data} fileName={fileName}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why the code for this should get "massive" - all you need to do is apply the classic *control break* mechanism of comparing the current row's value for a column, with that of the previous one. Only here you want to do it from left to right - and once the value in one column is *not* like that of the previous row any more, you break it off and don't modify the following columns any more.

```
const modified = [];
const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

data.forEach(function(e, i) {
  let clone = { ...e }
  modified.push(clone);
  if (i > 0) {
    for (const k of keys) {
      if (data[i - 1][k] === clone[k]) {
        clone[k] = '';
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});

console.log(modified)
```

Result:

```
0: {id: 1,  serviceId: 1,  title: 'A', model: 'A'}
1: {id: '', serviceId: '', title: 'T', model: 'b'}
2: {id: '', serviceId: 2,  title: 'R', model: 'A'}
3: {id: 2,  serviceId: 55, title: 'Q', model: 'A'}
4: {id: 3,  serviceId: 58, title: 'S', model: 'p'}
5: {id: '', serviceId: '', title: '',  model: 'm'}
6: {id: '', serviceId: 66, title: 'y', model: 'A'}
```